# How to import and use fonts in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, sass, fonts

I am trying to make my fonts work in my angular project with local font files. So I have a font `Univers LT`, the files are placed in `assets/fonts` along with the `fonts.scss` file. This I have then declared in `angular.json`:

```js
"styles":[
 //... other styles
 "src/assets/fonts/fonts.scss"
 ]
```

Below is my `font.scss`:

```css
@font-face {
font-family: 'UniversBlack';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Univers LT Std 75 Black'), url('UniversLTStd-Black.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

When I for example what to used `UniverseBlack`, in the `h1` tag. I go `font-family: 'UniverseBlack'`, which under my understanding should do the job, but it doesn't! Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: @gavgrif that was a typo in the question, no typo in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**N.B**: Use css extension for font instead of scss, it might solve your problem. I have implemented your font and works just fine. Here is what I did so far.

In assets folder file structure should be:

```
> UniversLTStd-Black.woff
> font.css
```

In font.css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Univers LT Std 75 Black';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Univers LT Std 75 Black'), url('UniversLTStd-Black.woff') format('woff');
}
```

This font can be attached in two ways.

**First way:**
you can add it angular.json. Then you have to restart by ng serve

**Second way**
import it in styles.css. Then it will work fine.

In styles.css:

```
@import "../src/assets/fonts/font.css";
```

Then in any component style:

```
 h1 {
font-family: 'Univers LT Std 75 Black';
}
```

Comment: mhm I have implemenet the second solution, but still doesn't do anything oddly!

Comment: make sure your font-face works correctly. Import it in any component and use it. Then you will understand if it works

Comment: if it doesn't work, provide the font, I can test it. or you can use stackblitz to demonstrate it.

Comment: Still doesn't do anything! I'm not sure I understand, how can I provide you with the font? The font is called `Univers Lt Std`! `https://www.cufonfonts.com/font/univers-lt-std`

Comment: please check updated answer. It might help you what I did to reproduce your font. I used font.css instead of font.scss

Comment: I have done it exactly like that but still nothing :( Could it be that its because im using `ttf` and not `woff`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199118/discussion-between-md-rafee-and-kontenurban).